# In Java, is substring(int k, int y) or substring(int k) more efficient performance wise?

Tags: java, string, performance, jvm, substring

For example, lets say I had the following code:

```
String s1 = "foobar";
s1 = s1.substring(3);
```

Would that code be less efficient than:

```
String s1 = "foobar";
s1 = s1.substring(3, 6);
```

I was thinking that the two parameter method would be more efficient performance wise because the single parameter method uses a loop to loop through the index until the length is reached. This means that the JVM has to call the `length()` method to find out when to stop looping.

But the two parameter method only loops through until the last index number is reached.

Can anyone confirm or deny my hypothesis?

EDIT:
I don't really understand this code in the source (last return statement) but here is the java String class source:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
     }
     if (endIndex > count) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
     }
    if (beginIndex > endIndex) {
    }
    return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == count)) ? this :    // I don't understand this part
         new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
}
```

Comment: Look into the source code of Strings.substring

Comment: You can confirm or deny it yourself by benchmarking both versions :)

Comment: Don't suffer from premature optimisation

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not. This was just a thought I had while sitting in class, I know not to do anything related to premature optimisation.

Comment: In a realistic example, to avoid calling substring(3), you would have to get the length of the string, and call `substring(3, s1.length())`, which is exactly what `substring(3)` does (but in a more verbose, less readable way). In your example, the most efficient version is `String s1 = "bar"`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`String.substring()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#String.substring(int%2Cint)) is constant time<sup>1</sup>, it simply provides smaller view on the original string. Moreover the version with one parameter just... delegates to the one with two:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex) {
    return substring(beginIndex, count);
}
```

Where `count` is the value returned by `String.length()`. It doesn't really matter which version you choose, they are both blazingly fast.

<sup>1</sup> - apparently [no longer true](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) as of Java 7 update 6. But it's irrelevant to your question.

Comment: I have upvoted enough for the day, else would have given +1 for those last two words. ;)

Comment: This is no longer true as of Java 7 Update 6. Now the backing `char[]` is always copied, making this O(n).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I'm shocked, can you provide some reference or pointer to source code (can't find it on grepcode)? Thanks for this information.

Comment: Just doing that, hang on. It's a mess over there at the official mercurial repo.

Comment: [Here it is](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java). Notice that `substring` calls the public constructor `String(char[], int, int)`, which, of course, defensively copies the `char[]`.

Comment: it is very shocking. they are gambling that it may not cause havoc.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I had not realised that they had actually completely removed the `count` and `offset` fields. The impact on substring is actually a side effect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any difference. If you see the String class source code substring(int beginIndex) -- simply calls the substring(beginIndex, lengthOfTheString)

Answer (score 1):

```
 public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

is slightly faster because

```
 public String substring(int beginIndex) {
      return substring(beginIndex, count);
 }
```

so you would avoid one indirection. But its is not worth to think about that.

Answer (score 0):

In java source code, `substring(beginIndex)` will invodke `substring(beginIndex, count)`